# Add Wordpress meta box to menu admin page

Tags: wordpress, menu, icons, meta-boxes

I know how to make meta boxes in pages and posts etc. But how do I add meta boxes to the menu page in the appearence -> menu page, for each menu item.

Add the moment, the menu items have to boxes: "Navigation Label" and "Titel Attribute". But I want to have another meta box for each menu item so the admin can type or choose a CSS class for, let's say, an icon.

The menu item "Home" should have an home icon, "About" an about icon and so on.

How do I accomplish that? Or is there an easy other way I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is built-in. Almost all screens have a <kbd>Screen Options</kbd> [feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Screens#Screen_Options). In `Appearence -> Menus`, it has an advanced option `CSS Classes`:

[image: css classes for navigation menus]

Comment: Omg, you're right! Thank you! However, the custom CSS Class appends to the list item. I use the Font Awesome CSS where I need the custom class to be appended to an <i> element, like: <a href="#"><i class="CUSTOM"></i>Menu Item</a>. You know how to accomplish that, with maybe custom walker class?

Comment: Yes, almost sure that if you need to customize the output, you'll need the walker class, but I don't have much experience with it. Take a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22walker+class%22).